# How to clear the pending jobs before it finished in python schedule module?

Tags: python-3.x, exe, schedule

Actually, I tried this solution, [Schedule python clear jobs queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259210/schedule-python-clear-jobs-queue). And it works as I expected.

But, I'm making a **simple parenting program**, that fetches the time from a sqlite database file.
[image: this is my database].

And when the time comes, program will show a notification. After 5 minuets, another notifications will show. 30 sec after the 2nd notification, program will execute logoff command.

**My code:**

```
def job():   
   toaster.show_toast(Title, MsgOne, icon_path=Icon) # 1st notification
   time.sleep(300) # Sleep for 5 mins
   toaster.show_toast(Title, MsgTwo, icon_path=Icon) # 2nd notification
   time.sleep(30) # Sleep for 30 sec
   os.system("shutdown -l") # logout 

schedule.every().day.at(TimeFajr).do(job) # Fajr
schedule.every().day.at(TimeDhuhr).do(job) # Dhuhr
schedule.every().day.at(TimeAsr).do(job) # Asr 
schedule.every().day.at(TimeMaghrib).do(job) # Maghrib 
schedule.every().day.at(TimeIshaa).do(job) # Isha'a 

while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

Everything's working fine. Even after converting it to exe ***(using auto-py-to-exe module)***. I made the program runs on background by adding it to windows startup folder.

**The problem is**, when I put my pc on sleep mode or lock my PC **BEFORE the time hits**, and log back in **AFTER the time passes**, the program runs the **QUEUED JOB** and logoff the system, even after the time passes. What I want is, that **QUEUED JOB** needs to be cleared or not to execute that one. I tried the solution on the link above, but it doesn't work after I convert it to exe. Without this, the program works fine. *(Sorry, my English is weak!)*

FYI, I'm new to python and this is my 1st project. If there's anyway other way that I can achieve what I'm doing, please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE:***

I figured out a way to do this finally.
I replaced the whole **scheduler** module with **[APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)**

A snippet from my code:

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler



def job():   
    toaster.show_toast(Title, MsgOne, icon_path=Icon) # 1st notification
    time.sleep(180) # Sleep for 3 mins
    toaster.show_toast(Title, MsgTwo, icon_path=Icon) # 2nd notification
    time.sleep(30) # Sleep for 30 sec
    toaster.show_toast(Title, MsgThree, icon_path=Icon) # 3rd notification
    #ctypes.windll.PowrProf.SetSuspendState(0, 1, 0) # This will put the PC on sleep
    os.system("rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation") # lock windows

scheduler.add_job(job, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=fajr_H, minute=fajr_M, misfire_grace_time=1)
scheduler.add_job(job, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=dhuhr_H, minute=dhuhr_M, misfire_grace_time=1)
scheduler.add_job(job, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=asr_H, minute=asr_M, misfire_grace_time=1)
scheduler.add_job(job, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=maghrib_H, minute=maghrib_M, misfire_grace_time=1)
scheduler.add_job(job, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=ishaa_H, minute=ishaa_M, misfire_grace_time=1)

scheduler.start()
```

This one worked as I wanted to.